# Google Maps not showing on webpage but shows on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-services, web

So I'm trying to implement Google maps on a website, and on my localhost it works fine, and I see it perfectly.
However when I upload this to my hosting company, the map doesn't show at all.
When I inspect the element and check the console, I don't see any errors.
Code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.092975, -7.895479);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom:16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'LCCEurotex'
    });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I have no idea what could be causing it as my code looks the same as the one from the google documentation.
Any ideas on what could be causing it would be great.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a link? I think this is an issue of a calling functions before they are loaded.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of network panel in chrome devtool?

Comment: Did you set your right API Key? What is the address of these coordinates?

Comment: try (<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>) and delete the one you are using

Comment: @howderek Hey, link is www.lcceurotex.com

Comment: @xzegga There is nothing on the network screen :S

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou Hey, that didn't work. Am I meant to put the api I got where it says api in your code? Because that gave me a 404, and it doesn't show anything without it either

Comment: In comments you cant format a link, that's why it appears as maps.google.....  see the answer below for the full link. sensor=false should be ok unless you require your co-ordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this portion of code to the footer page, Probably you has binding the map and div container is not property loaded, additionally, tray adding a heigth to the id map_canvas as default in your css.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDo7nFkoUthlGms4De0miS4EPfupB5x0cY"></script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.092975, -7.895479);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom:16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'LCCEurotex'
        });


      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

In your CSS

```
div#map-canvas {
  height: 500px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only add http:// to url of google maps api, change this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

By this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: I added in <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>  but it still didn't fix the issue :S

Comment: If you view your network panel notice that this library it's not found cuz it's loaded localy in your server, placing http:// or https:// should be resolve your problem

Comment: Hey sorry I only noticed now that it formatted the address I posted. i used http and it didn't work